# Can I :nth-child(10-infinity)?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am looking to select for all the `<li>`s from number 10 on up. I would rather have css, but javascript/ jquery is okay if necessary.

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 14):

```
li:nth-child(n + 10) {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhVNN/9/

---

*"And what if I wanted to select for lets say only 10 through 25?"*
:

```
li:nth-child(n + 10):nth-child(-n + 25) {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhVNN/8/

Comment: This does have some limited support.  See caniuse.com for more details.

Comment: It would be better to use an `ol` than a `ul` in that fiddle so it's obvious at a glance that it starts at #10.

Comment: An alternative that works for IE7 and IE8 would be `li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li` but that can get a little unwieldy :)

Comment: If IE7/8 support is required, selectivizr can be used.

Comment: And what if I wanted to select for lets say only 10 through 25?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `gt:` selector - http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul li:gt(9)').css('color', 'red'); // indexing starts from 0
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/udNrS/2/